# What was Ahiru's pendant?

Tags: anime, princess-tutu

In [Princess Tutu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Tutu), Ahriu is given a pendant that detects pieces of the prince's heart, and allows her to turn into Princess Tutu so she can return them to him.

In the penultimate episode,

> Ahiru tries to avoid giving Mytho the last piece of his heart, because it's actually the gem she's been using to turn into Princess Tutu - and without it, she'd revert to her *true* original form, a duck.
>  But I don't recall it being stated just *what* that piece of heart was.  I thought it might be Love, but that was in Akt 11 [La Sylphide](http://princesstutu.wikia.com/wiki/La_Sylphide).  Wikipedia and the rest of the Princess Tutu wikia [doesn't](http://princesstutu.wikia.com/wiki/Heart_Shards) [say](http://princesstutu.wikia.com/wiki/Pendant), so does anyone know which emotion turned Ahiru into Princess Tutu?
>  Bonus points if you also know what the shards from the five gates to the town were.

Comment: @AnkitSharma How so?  All the extra detail is in the question body, and I'd prefer not putting a spoiler for the climax of the entire series into the title...

Comment: TV Tropes identifies the last shard as Courage, based on the fact that courage tells her what to do with the last shard; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WMG/PrincessTutu